# I need to reference a custom field I created in User Profile

Tags: views, 7, entities

I used Drupal 7 computed fields to calculate weight loss. This is what I current have. Which works in a sense but only where the user inputs their initial weight and subtracts their current weight to track the total weight loss at the time of the input. But I need it to reference their initial weight from their user profile so that they only have to enter their current weight. One step process versus having to always enter the data that already exists. How can I achieve this?

Current Code which works great but two fields have to be filled in. Needs to reference field in user profile.

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = ($entity->field_iweight['und'][0]['value']) - ($entity->field_current_weight_['und'][0]['value']);
```

Comment: global $user is always available if you want to access the fields from the logged in user.

Comment: I am sorry to ask how would i put that into the syntax? or I guess query? I am very new to this. I have a little coding experience but it is not strong yet. :) unlike you awesome experts here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$user` object to access the logged in user.

```
 global $user;
 $account = user_load($user->uid);
```

Now you can use `$account->field_iweight['und'][0]['value']` (just an example) to access the weight or any other field from the user profile.

Updated code:

```
<?php
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $account->field_iweight['und'][0]['value'] - $entity->field_current_weight['und'][0]['value'];
?>
```

Comment: Um ok so I am not sure if I made a mistake doing this. I attempted to configure the computed field per the example above. I hit save but now I am unable to access the dashboard as an admin or regular user. Now I am trying to figure out how to correct this. :) Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you use PHP input format ? 

can you paste the entire code you used ?

Comment: I probably messed this up. Sorry for all the headaches. I appreciate your patience.

global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);

$entity_field[0]['value'] = ($account->field_iweight['und'][0]['value']) - ($entity->field_current_weight_['und'][0]['value']);

Comment: I updated the code segment in my answer. Is it $entity->field_current_weight_[...] is there an _ at the end of the field name?

Comment: Yeah that is the way it was created. I unintentionally left the extra _ there. Thank you again one question? How do I insert the code if I am unable to access it via the online interface?

Comment: you can go to admin/structure/types and see if you can edit it ?

Comment: Doesn't work. The site will only load the front page. Once I try to access the dashboard by logging in it hits the http 500 error.

Comment: It doesn't allow authentication at all. Am I able to get to the field via ftp and editing a php file? Or is it something stored in the db?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1045328 this might help you

Comment: Ok I fixed it. I just deleted the directory and re-installed the module. I was able to get the code to save but it isn't displaying the calculation.

Comment: are field_weight and field_current_weight on the user profile ?

Comment: I made a mistake on the field names. But I corrected it but it did not correct the issue. I placed this as my code field_weight_loss is what is used for the current weight. So I updated these accordingly but nothing seems to work. I am racking my brain to try and get this to work. It is in the user profile but it doesn't seem to be loading or something.


'<?php
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $account->field_initial_weight_['und'][0]['value'] - $entity->field_weight_loss['und'][0]['value'];
?>'

Comment: try without the php elements at the beginning and end of the code ?